# не выдает фон в канвасе

Tags: javascript, изображения, canvas

Я хочу добавить возможность изменять фон игры, так что я сделал это.

```js
// image background night
backgroundNightImg = new Image();
backgroundNightImg.src = 'images/background.png';

// image background day
let backgroundDayImg = new Image();
backgroundDayImg.src = 'images/background-day.png';
```

потом я сделал это`let isDayBackground = true;`
и внутри`document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {` сделал `onload` для фонов and `if` `statements` на кнопку, чтобы иметь возможность изменить фон.

С инглиш стаковерфлоу сказали что мне стоит использовать `window.onload` но это не помогло

```js
window.onload = fucntion() {
    let isDayBackground = true;
    board = document.getElementById('board');
    ground = document.getElementById('ground');
    boardWidth = board.width;
    boardHeight = board.height;
    context = board.getContext('2d');
    backgroundDayImg.onload = () => {
        context.drawImage(backgroundDayImg, 0, 0, boardWidth, boardHeight);
        console.log('Image loaded');
    };
    backgroundNightImg.onload = () => {
        console.log('Night background image loaded');
        if (!isDayBackground) {
            context.drawImage(backgroundNightImg, 0, 0, boardWidth, boardHeight);
        }
    };
    let changeBackrBtn = document.querySelector('#changeBackground');
    changeBackrBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        isDayBackground = !isDayBackground;
        if(isDayBackground){
            context.drawImage(backgroundDayImg, 0, 0, boardWidth, boardHeight);
        } else{
            context.drawImage(backgroundNightImg, 0, 0, boardWidth, boardHeight);
        }
        console.log('background changed');
    });
};
```

```css
#board{
    /* background-image: url('images/background-day.png'); */
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: 5px solid;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
div class="gameContainer">
        <canvas id="board" width="400px" height="620px"></canvas>
        <div class="ground"></div>
    </div>
    <button id="changeBackground">change background</button>
```

Также добавил `onerror` чтобы проверить на ошибки, и никаких ошибок нет

```js
    backgroundDayImg.onerror = () =>{
        console.error('Ошибка загрузки фона день');
    } 
    backgroundNightImg.onerror = () =>{
        console.error('Ошибка загрузки фона ночь');
    }
```

Проблема в том, что они не меняются, "однако консоль говорит, что они загружены и изменены", ChatGPT говорит, что всё в порядке и должно работать, но на самом деле это не происходит.
[Это доказывает, что консоль сообщает, что изображения загружаются и как бы отображаются.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GwKE.png)            [проблема](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXxak.png)

Comment: Все должно меняться. Проверьте пути до файлов изображений и добавьте обработчик для события ``onerror``, чтобы увидеть ошибку при загрузке. ``DOMContentLoaded`` тут не нужен. Вот тут все работает [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-m8wzms?file=index.js).